# How to prevent a single row of <img> from turning into 2 rows after a zoom in

Tags: html

My ducks. I want to keep them in a row. However, when I zoom in, they smash together and make two rows. What can I do to have them simply not show/stay in one row when zoomed in instead?

Code is here, these ducks live in a 2x1 table

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Check out deez ducks:</td>
  <td><img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" height="150" width="96"><img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" height="150" width="96"><img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" height="150" width="96"><img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" height="150" width="96"><img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" height="150" width="96"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/myn2qarf/

Gif of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfj9L.jpg

---

**EDIT:** Found the answer, needed to add "nowrap" to the td containing the ducks. So, if before I had:

```
<td> *Ducks go here* </td>
```

I ended up needing

```
<td nowrap> *Ducks go here* </td>
```

Comment: No need to read any of the answers, they're all crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! I needed to add "nowrap" to the  element, this prevents the images from wrapping. So, my code was modified from

```
<td> *images of ducks* </td>
```

to

```
<td nowrap> *images of ducks* </td>
```

Comment: Then accept your own answer, to the benefit of the next coder!

Comment: I.....I can't find the accept button ._. Is there a minimum period of time a question has to be up before I'm allowed to?


EDIT: Found the button, but can't accept it for 2 days

Comment: It's the V check mark. There is a minimum though - clicking will tell you if you're below it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the image in percentage. 20% seems to work nice in this case.

Comment: For my application, I have no control over the width of the images and must be able to accept any reasonable width of one.

Co-worker just took a look at my problem apparently adding "nowrap" to the td fixed it. so <td nowrap> *ducks go here* </td> was the solution. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea would be, if you don't want a zoomed image to offset another one, to give it an absolute position and put a placeholder behind it. Like so:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="img-cell">
        <img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" />
        <div class="img-spacer"></div>
        <img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" />
        <div class="img-spacer"></div>
        <img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" />
        <div class="img-spacer"></div>
        <img src="http://www.mapleleaffarms.com/lib/sitefiles/White-Duck_Facing_Front.jpg" />
        <div class="img-spacer"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.img-cell {
  font-size: 0px;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
img:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
.img-spacer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwZWRe

If that's what you want.

Also, +1 for making your question fun.

P.S.: Your fiddle didn't let me zoom. I'm on Firefox, if you care.

Answer (score 1):

add the images in div and put some css check here -> [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhra6tt1/)

```
.flex-style {
display: flex;
width: 100%;}
```